# ReactJS Firebase authenticated user set in Context API global state but values are only available through a null check?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-context

This isn't a problem exactly, but I'm really confused by how this works. I'm using Firebase authentication and in my App.js, I set user to global state through onAuthStateChanged like so.

```
const auth = firebase.auth();

useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      console.log("THE USER IS >>> ", authUser);
      if (authUser) {
        // the user just logged in / the user was logged in
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: authUser,
        });
      } else {
        // the user is logged out
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: null,
        });
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

I then want to reference the stored state of user in a component. However, if I try to directly reference the component I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of null, where null is supposed to be user.

```
const [{user}, dispatch] = useStateValue();

return (
        <div className="container">
                <p>{user.password}</p>
        </div>
    )
```

However, if I set a null check on user, it works.

```
const [{user}, dispatch] = useStateValue();

return (
        <div className="container">
                <p>{!user ? "You need to login" : user.email}</p>
        </div>
    )
```

I'm guessing user needs to be called from Firebase before it's available to be called. But if this is stored in global state, why does it need to be called again before it's available? Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1):

Where did you wrap your components with AuthProvider? on App.js or on .index.js?

You need to wrap the parent component with the context Provider before using it by the childs.

Comment: AuthProvider was in App.js, and App.js wraps all child components. The reducer passes initial state and actions to the context Provider and that wraps around App.js in index.js.